# ReactJs not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have little problems with my ReactJs app, I'm receiving message like:

```
./src/components/Navbar/index.js
  Line 13:3:  'state' is not defined        no-undef
  Line 17:3:  'handleClick' is not defined  no-undef
```

I'm beginner with JavaScript and it's  seams it's easy fix, I just copied that code from another app where it works.

This is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Layout, Menu, Drawer, Icon } from 'antd';
import { Mobile, Default } from '../Responsive';

import './index.less';

const { Header } = Layout;
const { SubMenu } = Menu;


const Navbar = props => {

  state = {
    current: 'home',
  };

  handleClick = e => {
    console.log('click ', e);
    this.setState({
      current: e.key,
    });
  };


  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const menu = (
    <Menu
      theme="lite"
      mode="horizontal"
      defaultSelectedKeys={['2']}
      style={{ lineHeight: '64px' }}
      onClick={this.handleClick} selectedKeys={[this.state.current]} mode="horizontal">
      <Menu.Item key="mail">
        <Icon type="mail" />
        Navigation One
        </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="app" disabled>
        <Icon type="appstore" />
        Navigation Two
        </Menu.Item>
      <SubMenu
        title={
          <span className="submenu-title-wrapper">
            <Icon type="setting" />
            Navigation Three - Submenu
            </span>
        }
      >
        <Menu.ItemGroup title="Item 1">
          <Menu.Item key="setting:1">Option 1</Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="setting:2">Option 2</Menu.Item>
        </Menu.ItemGroup>
        <Menu.ItemGroup title="Item 2">
          <Menu.Item key="setting:3">Option 3</Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="setting:4">Option 4</Menu.Item>
        </Menu.ItemGroup>
      </SubMenu>
      <Menu.Item key="alipay">
        <a href="https://ant.design" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
          Navigation Four - Link
          </a>
      </Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
  );

  return (
    <Header className="app-header">
      <Default>{menu}</Default>
      <Mobile>
        <Icon type="bars" size="large" className="nav-icon" onClick={() => setVisible(true)} />
        <Drawer
          title=""
          placement="left"
          closable
          onClose={() => setVisible(false)}
          visible={visible}
          className="nav-drawer"
        >
          {menu}
        </Drawer>
      </Mobile>
    </Header>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

I copied this state and handleClick from another app but it was class, I tried to change `const Navbar` with `class NavBar extends Component` but no success.

Comment: You have copied this code from a class component so it won't work with a functional component. Either make your component a class component or add another use state for current

Comment: I tried and then I have error for consts

Answer (score 6):

You are mixing react components and react hooks. You should either use hook (useState), or components (this).

Here is your code with hooks

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Layout, Menu, Drawer, Icon } from 'antd';
import { Mobile, Default } from '../Responsive';

import './index.less';

const { Header } = Layout;
const { SubMenu } = Menu;


function Navbar(props) {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState('home');
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  function handleClick(e) {
    console.log('click ', e);
    setCurrent(e.key)
  };

  const menu = (
    <Menu
      theme="lite"
      mode="horizontal"
      defaultSelectedKeys={['2']}
      style={{ lineHeight: '64px' }}
      onClick={this.handleClick} selectedKeys={[current]} mode="horizontal">
      <Menu.Item key="mail">
        <Icon type="mail" />
        Navigation One
        </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="app" disabled>
        <Icon type="appstore" />
        Navigation Two
        </Menu.Item>
      <SubMenu
        title={
          <span className="submenu-title-wrapper">
            <Icon type="setting" />
            Navigation Three - Submenu
            </span>
        }
      >
        <Menu.ItemGroup title="Item 1">
          <Menu.Item key="setting:1">Option 1</Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="setting:2">Option 2</Menu.Item>
        </Menu.ItemGroup>
        <Menu.ItemGroup title="Item 2">
          <Menu.Item key="setting:3">Option 3</Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="setting:4">Option 4</Menu.Item>
        </Menu.ItemGroup>
      </SubMenu>
      <Menu.Item key="alipay">
        <a href="https://ant.design" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
          Navigation Four - Link
          </a>
      </Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
  );

  return (
    <Header className="app-header">
      <Default>{menu}</Default>
      <Mobile>
        <Icon type="bars" size="large" className="nav-icon" onClick={() => setVisible(true)} />
        <Drawer
          title=""
          placement="left"
          closable
          onClose={() => setVisible(false)}
          visible={visible}
          className="nav-drawer"
        >
          {menu}
        </Drawer>
      </Mobile>
    </Header>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything else looks fine except:

```
const [current, setCurrent] = useState('home') ;

const handleClick = e => {
    console.log('click ', e);
    setCurrent(e.key);
  };
```

Actually you have to convert the this.state to hook as well.